# Filling a grid view with data of a table where one of the columns=one of the columns in a list

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a list with two columns in it: ID; int, Score: Double.

In addition, I have a table in SQL SERVER with several columns.One of them is id:int.

I want to have a query like below:

select * from tbl where id = id s in my list.

My codes are below:

```
 protected void btnfind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<KeyValuePair<int, double>> candidatelist = CalculateScores();
        FinalMatch(candidatelist);
        BindGrid(cmd2);//Contains codes for filling grid view with cmd2 , sql data reader
 }

protected void FinalMatch(List<KeyValuePair<int, double>> finallist)
{
    DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
    tvp = ConvertToDatatable(finallist);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd2.CommandText = "dbo.DoSomethingWithCandidates";
    SqlParameter tvparam = cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@List", tvp);
    tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    cmd2.Connection = ClsDataBase.con;
}

protected DataTable ConvertToDatatable(List<KeyValuePair<int, double>> finallist)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Score");
    foreach (var item in finallist)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["ID"] = item.Key;
        row["Score"] = item.Value;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return dt;
}

protected void BindGrid(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    if (ClsDataBase.con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        ClsDataBase.con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        if (dr1.HasRows)
        {
            gv_allresults.DataSource = dr1;
            gv_allresults.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('No Match')</script>");

        }
        if (dr1.IsClosed == false) dr1.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {

        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(\"" + ex.ToString() + "\")</script>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(\"" + ex.ToString() + "\")</script>");

    }
    finally
    {
        ClsDataBase.con.Close();
    }

}
```

And my codes in SQL server are:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CandidateList
AS TABLE
(
  ID INT,
   Score FLOAT
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoSomethingWithCandidates
   @List AS dbo.CandidateList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT ID FROM @List; 
END
GO
```

I don't get the result. My procedure's codes are not complete. I don`t know what to do. Please help me.
Thanks so much.

---

Edited codes according to given suggestion:

```
 protected void FinalMatch(List<KeyValuePair<int, double>> finallist)
{
    int[] canArr = finallist.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
    string csv = string.Join(",", canArr);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd2.CommandText = "dbo.ReturnCandidates";
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIST", csv);
    cmd2.Connection = ClsDataBase.con;

}
```

And new codes in Sql server are:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
  (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
RETURN
END
GO



CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ReturnCandidates
(
 @LIST VARCHAR(200)
 ) 
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT  *
 FROM    tblspecifications
 WHERE   id IN ( SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@LIST) )
END
```

I get this error: "Procedure or function ReturnCandidates has too many arguments specified",
In below line:

SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Please help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()` missing.

Also, why not make a comma separated list of ID's and then send it to the SQL function. Example

```
int[] canArr= candidatelist.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
string csv = string.Join(",", canArr);
```

**EDIT:**

I created a SQL Fiddle for your query. It works. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3d013/1/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I put codes for binding Grid View in BindGrid(cmd) function. I edited my codes above and put BindGrid function. Can you explain more how to use this array in SQL? If I want to show the scores in GridView,what should I do?

Comment: After searching a lot and trying different ways, I think one way was the best according what you suggested me. But now,I get an error. I tried to solve that with different ways but it didn`t have any result. I added my new code above. It gets on my nerves. Please help me

Comment: Please check the edit. Also, I ll suggest using a DataSet then DataReader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I`m struggling with this. When I use data set, I can get result for both ways I tried(using user-defined table type,..., and using comma separated list). I don't know why I couldn`t get result when  used Data Reader. But the problem is that I want to use both data in my list, I mean ID:int, Score:double. I want to order by Score , but I can`t ,Although I tried different ways. Please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Finally, I get my answer: I should use ORDER BY like this: "ORDER BY (SELECT top(1) Score from @list li where mytable.id = li.id)". Why  did you suggest me to use data set? I used Data Reader, because I have read it is faster.  why I couldn`t get result when used Data Reader?

Comment: Data Reader and Adapter are meant for different situations. Data Adapter is used when you want to have a disconnected scenario. When you just want to fetch data from DB and show it, Data Adapter is best suited for this. While for a requirement where you need to have a live connection between database and simultaneous read/update data, you will choose data reader.